# Odd or even row dot product based on order of Matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

For a given NxN matrix what is not the value of N such that the dot product of a row with itself will be even and dot product of any row with a different row is odd.
a) 2k b) 2k,4k,4k+1 c) 4k

Comment: this was asked to my friend in a written interview test, am unable to understand question properly.
I am unable to see any logic why order can affect dot product to be odd or even shouldn't it depend on entries in matrix?
So I thought I might be missing something and hence asked this question here

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas that may help the thought process, presented as a HINT. Given that any row must dot as odd with any other row, there is not a zero row mod 2 (no row with all even values). Given that any row dots even with itself, each row has an even number of odd elements.

Consider

$$\pmatrix{0 & 1 & 1& 1&\\ 1& 0& 1& 1& \cdots\\ 1& 1& 0& 1& \\ 1& 1& 1& 0& \\ \vdots & & & & \ddots }$$

This shows existence for any $N = 2k + 1$.

Next consider the smallest even dimension $N =2$ ...

Comment: I didn't get how it shows existence for N = 2k + 1

Comment: Take for instance $\pmatrix{0 & 1 & 1\\ 1& 0& 1\\ 1& 1& 0\\}$ with $N = 3$ and calculate the various dot products of rows. Can you see how this generalizes for any odd $N$?

Comment: thanks
what about multiple of 4?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/329939/43193) (first link in the related column for this question) might give you some more ideas.