# Revisited - Number of $(0,1)$ $n \times n$ matrices with exactly $k$ ones and no row or column contains only zeros

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

Long time listener, first time caller here. I am experimenting with matrices and want to know the number of valid combinations for a binary {0,1} $n \times n$ matrix based on density\sparsity. Combinatorics seems like it might provide a calculation method, but the inclusion-exclusion calculations are new to me.  I have a thorough understanding of set theory and basics in combination/permutation calculations.

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439596/number-of-0-1-m-times-n-matrices-with-no-empty-rows-or-columns) talks about a {0,1} $m \times n$ matrix that has no empty rows or columns. (Moreover, every row and column has at least one 1) Brian M. Scott concludes with an inclusion-exclusion calculation for a sum of possible valid combinations for an $m \times n$ matrix.
Note: Because my matrix is square, I've replace $m$ with $n$.

I confirmed the first few cases with my own inspection and this works for $n=1, 2, 3$.
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k(-1)^k\left(2^{n-k}-1\right)^n\tag{1}
$$

[Another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168313/number-of-0-1-m-times-n-matrices-with-exactly-k-ones-and-no-row-or-colu?noredirect=1&lq=1) talks about a similar {0,1} $m \times n$  matrix but calculates with a restriction number $k$ of 1s contained within. It also has the same condition that every row and column have at least one 1.
'bof' gives an inclusion-exclusion calculation, I have substituted $n$ for $m$ (this might be invalid?), and have confirmed upon inspection that the calculation is correct for $n=1,2,3$.

$$
\sum_{u=0}^n\sum_{v=0}^n(-1)^{u+v}\binom nu\binom nv\binom{(n-u)(n-v)}k\tag{2}
$$

and 'bof' concludes with
$$
\sum_{r=0}^n\sum_{s=0}^n(-1)^{2n+r+s}\binom nr\binom ns\binom{rs}k.\tag{3}
$$

Here is the interesting part, summing $(3)$ from $k=0$ to $n$ should reproduce the calculation found in $(1)$.
And it does for $n=1,2,3,4$.
But once $n\geq5$, the calculations differ!
The following are tables of my results:

$n=1$ is trivial

$n=2$

| k | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | sum | $(1)$ | difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 0 | 0 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 7 | 7 | 0 |

$n=3$

| k | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | sum | $(1)$ | difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 45 | 90 | 78 | 36 | 9 | 1 | 265 | 265 | 0 |

$n=4$

| k | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | ~ | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | sum | $(1)$ | difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 24 | 432 | ~ | 1812 | 560 | 120 | 16 | 1 | 41503 | 41503 | 0 |

$n=5$

| k | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | ~ | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | sum | $(1)$ | difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 120 | ~ | 12650 | 2300 | 300 | 25 | 1 | 24997921 | 24997916 | 5 |

$n=6$

| k | ~ | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | ~ | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35 | 36 | sum | $(1)$ | difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | ~ | 0 | 720 | 43200 | 755100 | 6700500 | ~ | 58905 | 7140 | 630 | 36 | 1 | 57366997447 | 57366986518 | 10929 |

There is some discrepancy between $(1)$ and summing the parts of $(3)$ when $n>=5$.

Any insight on if I've made a mistaken substitution, I've used the calculations incorrectly, or something else missed would be immensely helpful.

Comment: OK, the tables were something to do with MathJax, I managed to save the formatting by adding more whitespace :) . Still, I suggest that instead of observing masses and masses of tables, that you focus on a single pair $n,k$ where the result of your calculation is different from what you expected.

Comment: One more thing regarding formatting. Always format *full* equations using Mathjax, not just parts of them. Writing `$n$=1,2,3` yields a very ugly "$n$=1,2,3", while `$n=1,2,3$` yields a much nicer "$n=1,2,3$". You might also be interested in the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: There is no discrepancy. You are computing the values of $(1)$ incorrectly for $n\in \{5,6\}$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, I'm surprised that you point to $(1)$ to be the problem, since its the easier sum to compute.  I checked my computation again and it seems to be correct with the calculation given.
I also checked $(2)$ and $(3)$ to be sure the substitution with the 2nd post works. I've confirmed it does up to n=5.
Could this be an issue with calculating large combinations in the program I'm using? Is there a common programming language for combinatorics? Maybe a python package for large numbers?

Comment: Python is great for integer math, since Python's default `int`'s have infinite precision. If you only use double precision, you can get overflow, and if you use floats, you can get rounding error. [This Python program](https://tio.run/##TY2xDoIwFEVn@hVvfK9CsBoXEhZ2J0fjgFi0aXgltQx@fW2VRLeb3HPPnV/h4Xgf402PMLjpilxaakRhRrDQtrBtwOuweAYlijV9uUqVtlIkua6tEHnfedPz8TS4EJCzZOWfy4RnzKy0IH83KeNOyqSy9GkZRufTr2HwPd818kbRhYSYveGA//4DUYxv) computes the $n=5$ case correctly. I can't comment on what is wrong with your program, since you haven't said what program you used or shared your code.

Comment: Thanks @MikeEarnest! This pointed me in the write direction.  I was doing quick calculations in Excel and the combination function got overwhelmed.